/handleClick route is not routing to rendered template in flask
I am not able to open test.html by rendering in flask.
I am trying to send data of a movie card to other page: test.html if the card is clicked.
I have taken the approach of onclick(event) function using embedded javascript.
Please help me in solving the problem mentioned below.
Below is flask route function
@app.route('/handleClick', methods=["GET"])
def handleClick():
    title = request.args.get('title')
    print(title)

    # Render the movie.html template with the data
    return render_template('test.html')

/handleClick is called by a embedded javascript on index.html
<script>
        function sendData(event){
            const clickedCard = event.target.closest('.small_card');
            // Extract data from the clicked card
            const title = clickedCard.querySelector('.labels h2').textContent;

            // Send an AJAX request to the Flask server with the data
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', '/handleClick?title=' + encodeURIComponent(title), true);
            xhr.send();
        }
    </script>

test.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
</body>
</html>

On clicking the card data is sent to flask server, also it getting printed in terminal. But test.html page is not opening.
I checked network panel of developer mode, there test.html is not getting displayed.

XmlHttpRequest.send() makes an http request, but it doesn't automatically do anything with the response -- that's up to your code.
If you want the browser to show a new page, you don't need XmlHttpRequest (or even fetch() which is an easier / more modern interface), you just want to set window.location.href to the new URL.

One thing to add, if you just want to load parts of a page, you'll want to make a request (preferably with fetch() as @Andrew says) and then replace the elements with the response of the request. If those parts contain EJS, you'll want to either already render the template with variables on the server and send it to the client to replace or make use of the client-side EJS ('Client-side support' almost at the end) and render the templates on the client.
